# Build both a Dynamic Library for release and Static Library for GTest

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-linking, googletest, dynamic-linking

I have a project that creates a dynamic library, the dll will be used by third party applications.

But to run googletests I need to create a static library, so how can I build both type of files?

Is there a post build event that would create a lib and a dynamic library.

How would you suggest I handle both cases, (maybe include all the files in my unit test and not link the library)?

Comment: Why don't you use a continuous integration system that runs the unit tests when you commit?

Comment: Not sure I follow, how would that help if the file is a Dynamic library DLL?
I would need to somehow change the configuration before running the tests and change it back afterwards.

Comment: If visual studio is too hard to configure, you could try using mingw and use a traditional makefile which is configurable, or any other traditional build system. Then use any CI system like jenkins, hudson, travis-ci, circle-ci, etc. and make it test with `make static test; ./test` or similar. I would think that you should be able to invoke msvc from command line alternatively, but I've never actually done that, and I don't know.

Comment: *But to run googletests I need to create a static library*  Building a static library is usually much more than doing a recompilation with a couple of different command-line switches.  You have to make sure that the final static library will actually work correctly (and even link correctly).  When using a static library, unless you've been careful, you may get linker errors due to using multiple instances of the same code i.e. functions, variables, etc., whereas with a DLL, this is no issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, that might be right, but I don't have that problem.
I can switch between static lib and dynamic dll.

Answer (score 0):

Build with this setting for tests

Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Configuration Type->Static Library

This for application

Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Configuration Type->Dynamic Library

Comment: Yes, of course, but I don't want to change the setting manually all the time.
I would prefer some 'automated' way otherwise I would need to disable my tests all the time while working with the third party applications, and that's most of my dev time.
I would only see test fail if/when I remember to change the Configuration type.
Not really practical.

Comment: I think it is much more practical than using complicated make files. I'm sure you can make a batch script that will switch the configuration, but switching this property takes very little time

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 projects. A static lib and a DLL

Have them both add same source.

Maybe have special code for initialisation (DllMain)